# Can not edit Genymotion Devices resolution

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, archlinux, genymotion

I have been using **Genymotion** on **ArchLinux** for a long time But now I ran into a problem

When I want to edit the resolution of the any genymotion devices, this edit is not applied
Also, the Android version of all devices is 0.0 for some reason

When I try to turn on the android device, it gives this error for me:

[image]

```
The version of Android used by Samsung Galaxy S9 is no longer supported.
To enjoy new features , please create a new one.
```

It seems to be a permissions error or something similar ...
how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you upgrade VirtualBox? VirtualBox 7.0 is not supported: https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/7185641408541

Comment: Yes. my virtualbox version is `7.0.2-1`

Comment: `downgrade` from 7.0 to 6.1.4 SOLVED problem.Also, the virtualbox kernel must be downgraded to 6.1.4 ... Thanks

Comment: 6.1.4 is rather old; 6.1.40 should work just fine :-). Also, Desktop 3.3.0 beta (stable release is coming soon) has introduced QEMU support and it runs fantastic on Linux (Ubuntu). Plus, it offers quick boot and no more VirtualBox dirty shenanigans.